# Is there a way to pass a method to a method of the same object?

Tags: ruby, methods

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
class Directory
  def doSomething
  end

  def subs
    # => an array of Directory objects
  end

  def recursively (method)
    self.subs.each do |sub|
      sub.method
      sub.recursively method
    end
  end
end

cd = Directory.new

cd.recursively 'doSomething'
# ...and extra points if theres a way to:
cd.recursively.doSomething
```

To put this into perspective I'm creating a small script that will make changes to files in a Directory as well as all its sub-directories. These sub-directories will just be extended `Directory` objects.

*So is there a way to pass a method as a parameter of another method?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send), where `method` is a string or symbol representing the method name, as in your first example. Just change your `#recursively` to this:

```
def recursively(method)
  subs.each do |sub|
    sub.send method
    sub.recursively method
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

For your "extra points" question, and picking up on megas' answer, here's a stab at an Enumerator-based approach. Drop this into your Directory:

```
def recursively
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    subs.each do |sub|
      y.yield sub
      sub.recursively.each do |e|
        y.yield e
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And call it like this:

```
cd.recursively.each { |d| d.doSomething }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this -

```
class Directory
    def doSomething
    end

    def subs
        # => an array of Directory objects
    end

    def recursively (method)
        self.subs.each do |sub|
            sub.method.call
            sub.recursively method
        end
    end
end

dir = Directory.new
ds = dir.method :doSomething

dir.recursively ds
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here's should be specialized `each` method from Enumerable module. When you implement the `each` method, then Enumerable module will give a lot of handy methods like `map, drop` and so on.

```
class Directory
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    # here you should build @objects - a whole list of all objects in 
    # the current direcory and its subdirectories.
    @objects = ....
  end

  def each         
    if block_given?
      @objects.each { |e| yield(e) }
    else
      Enumerator.new(self, :each)
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

And then you can iterate all objects in elegant way:

```
@directory = Directory.new('start_directory')

@directory.each do |object|
  puts object.size # this will prints the sizes for all objects in directory
  object.do_some_job # this will call method on object for all your objects
end
```

This one will give an array of sizes for all objects in directory

```
@directory.map { |object| object.size } #=> [435435,64545,23434,45645, ...]
```

Aditional example:

For example you need to get the list with indexes and sizes of all objects

```
@directory.each_with_index.map { |object, index| [index, object.size] }

#=> [ [0,43543], [1,33534], [2,34543564], [3,345435], ...]
```

Comment: I'd like to say that I really like the semantics of this route so far. What exactly does the `block_given?` check for?

Comment: I think this is going to be a huge help for my project and I thank you for the effort. I do think ultimately though that the answer @Rob Davis provided better answers the initial question. So I'll check his for any future visitors. If I could upvote you more I would.

Comment: I like the enumerator idea, too, although it's probably best not to gather up the entire tree into @objects at the beginning. Imagine if you tried this approach to search the file system. You wouldn't want an array of all of your computer's directories. See my answer for a leaner way to enumerate the tree depth-first.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you headed in the right direction:

```
module Recursion
  def recursively(&block)
    output = block.call(self)
    output.recursively(&block) unless output.nil?
  end
end

class Number
  include Recursion

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def next
    @value > 0 ? Number.new(@value - 1) : nil
  end

  def print
    puts @value
    self.next
  end
end

Number.new(10).recursively(&:print)
```